# Disconnect a BLE peripheral in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have some issues to disconnect a BLE peripheral in Swift. First, I tried to use only the `cancelPeripheralConnection:` function. But if I just call this function, the `didDisconnectPeripheral` function is never called. So I tried to follow [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html) reference guide. There is say's, that you should delete every notifications before disconnecting. Is this really necessary? And is there a possibility to cancel all notifications in one step? I set up a lot of notifications, so I have to search in many services and characteristics to reset them. I guess, that can't be a "well done" solution.

**EDIT:**
Okay I figured out, that the `cancelPeripheralConnection` works pretty well, if I call it in my `BluetoothManager` class, where `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralDelegate` are included... Is there a way to disconnect to a peripheral outside of this function?

**EDIT 4:**

```
import UIKit

class ValueCollectionView: UICollectionViewController
{
    var valueCollectionViewCell: ValueCollectionViewCell = ValueCollectionViewCell()
    var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        bluetoothManager.disconnectPeripheral(selectedPeripheralIndex!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
//Some Collection View functions...
}
```

And this is my implementation of the `disconnectPeripheral` function (integrated in the BluetoothManager class):

```
func disconnectPeripheral(peripheralIndex: Int)
{
    CBmanager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheralArray![peripheralIndex].peripheral)
}
```

But anyway, if I call this function, the `didDisconnectPeripheral` function isn't called. When I put the function in the BluetoothManager class e.g. after I discovered the last characteristic, everything works.

**EDIT 5:**

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
{
    var CBmanager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.CBmanager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func connectPeripheral(peripheralIndex: Int)
    {
        CBmanager.connectPeripheral(peripheralArray![peripheralIndex].peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func disconnectPeripheral(peripheralIndex: Int)
    {
        CBmanager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheralArray![peripheralIndex].peripheral)
    }

//The other CentralManager functions...

}
```

Comment: How are you trying to call cancelPeripheralConnection? You need to call it in the instance of the CBCentralManager that has the connection

Comment: I added my two different classes. The BluetoothManager class contains the delegate functions and the ValueCollectionView class should disconnect the BLE connection when pressing the back button.

Comment: Having the Bluetooth functions in a view controller isn't a very good design because you are mixing the two functions and need to keep a reference to a view controller that may not be needed. It would be better to move all of your Bluetooth functions into a separate Bluetooth object and pass a reference to that object where needed

Comment: I tried to implement it like you said, but the didDisconnectPeripheral function isn't called anyway.

Comment: You need to ensure you are only instantiating a single instance of the Bluetooth class (and therefore CBCentral).

Comment: What does it mean? Sorry I'm not so familiar with object orientated languages :)

Comment: If you can show the code where you try to disconnect (I mean the code that calls your Bluetooth object, not the code inside that object) it will help.  If you do something like `let btManager=MyBluetoothClass()  btManager.disconnect()` it won't work.

Comment: I hope, my edit shows what you are searching for.

Comment: What I want to know is how you call `BluetoothManager.disconnectPeripheral(int)` ?  - Specifically are you creating a single instance of this class and passing it around or are you creating a second instance?

Comment: Ahh gotcha! That#s it! I created two instances :) Right now, I solved it with a global instance, is there a better way to go?

Comment: Nope, you need to make sure you have a single CBCentral instance.  You don't have to use a global, you can just set it as a property on each view controller as you create it or whatever

Comment: Thank you! If you create an answer, I will vote for you :)

Comment: Abhinav's answer basically says the same thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To your first doubt, yes we should deregister from subscribed characteristics before disconnecting from peripheral for a reason given in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html):

> **Note:** The `cancelPeripheralConnection:` method is nonblocking, and any
>   `CBPeripheral` class commands that are still pending to the peripheral
>   you’re trying to disconnect may or may not finish executing. Because
>   other apps may still have a connection to the peripheral, canceling a
>   local connection does not guarantee that the underlying physical link
>   is immediately disconnected. From your app’s perspective, however, the
>   peripheral is considered disconnected, and the central manager object
>   calls the `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` method of its
>   delegate object.

Now, coming to your other question -

> Is there a way to disconnect to a peripheral outside of this function?

You need to disconnect it from the instance you instantiated and started connection on. As long as you can call the cancellation on the same object it should work.

```
myCentralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
```

In my application, I had to use BLE features from many different classes which led me to write a singleton `MyBLEManager` and all the classes were coming to this singleton for all BLE related activities. This deal works great and help troubleshooting confined to one class only. You can try this out.

Comment: Ok, but how can I ensure, that I use the same instance in both cases? Because I call var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = BluetoothManager() one time in my UITableView and one time in my UICollection view. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes - thats a problem. You should create singleton class. That works like charm ensuring only one object to deal with all the time.